# p:dataTable multiple selection not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, facelets, mojarra

I don't seem to get multiple selection in PrimeFaces dataTables working.

I'm trying to implement a list of clients (dataList) and show their respective bookings in nested dataTables with a possibility to select multiple bookings for billing:

```
<p:dataList value="#{clientController.allClients}" var="client">
<p:column>
    <p:dataTable value='#{client.bookingsDataModel}' var='item' selection="#{client.bookingsToBill}">
        <p:column selectionMode="multiple" />
    </p:dataTable>
</p:column>
</p:dataList>
```

My controller and backing bean classes:

```
public class ClientController {
    public List<Client> getAllClients() {
        return clients;
    }
}

public class Client {

    private List<Booking> bookings;
    private Booking[] bookingsToBill;

    public LeistungDataModel getBookingsDataModel() { 
        return new BookingsDataModel(bookings); 
    }

    public Booking[] getBookingsToBill() { 
        return bookingsToBill; 
    }

    public void setBookingsToBill(Booking[] bookingsToBill) { 
        this.bookingsToBill = bookingsToBill;
    }

}
```

The data model class:

```
public class BookingsDataModel extends ListDataModel<Booking> implements SelectableDataModel<Booking> {    

    public BookingsDataModel(List<Booking> data) {  
        super(data);  
    }  

    @Override  
    public Booking getRowData(String rowKey) { 
        List<Booking> bookings = (List<Booking>) getWrappedData();
        for(Booking booking : bookings) {  
            if(("booking_"+booking.getId().toString()).equals(rowKey)) {
                return booking;
            } 
        }
        return null;  
    }  

    @Override  
    public Object getRowKey(Booking booking) {  
        return "booking_"+booking.getId().toString();  
    }

}
```

The browser posts the following data to the server, when I submit the form with my selections:

```
j_idt9%3Aj_idt13%3A0%3Aj_idt15_selection:booking_300,booking_301,booking_302
j_idt9%3Aj_idt13%3A1%3Aj_idt15_selection:booking_566,booking_567
j_idt9%3Aj_idt13%3A2%3Aj_idt15_selection:
```

Also, I found during debugging that the `getRowData` method of the `BookingsDataModel` returns the correct `Booking` objects (the selected ones).

However, always empty arrays are passed to the `setBookingsToBill` of my `Client` objects. What could be going wrong here?

---

**Update:**

An empty array is only passed the first `Client` objects - it doesn't matter if a booking has been selected or not. All other `Client` objects' `setBookingsToBill` methods are called with a parameter value of `null`.

Comment: Please provide primefaces version

Answer (score -1):

Not really, if you want multiple selection with check box you have to do as jfs did:

In the showcase there is one example showing just that. It will create a column containing the boxes for the user to select. You can also do as you've said, using an attribute of p:dataTable, however this will not create the boxes and the user will have to control+click to do multiple select.

Answer (score -3):

The selectionMode should be a part of the `<p:dataTable>` tag.

Here is a link to the showcase which has an example.
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionMultiple.jsf

Comment: See comment by Felipe - this will remove the checkboxes - and allow multiple select by control/command clicking